# Comparing values of each integer within a range

Tags: python

```
n= int(raw_input(" Enter a number"))
i = 0 
length = 0 
maxLength = 0 

for i in range(1, n - 1):
              if length > maxLength:
              maxLength = length 
              i = i + 1
*run other program which gets value*
code 
code 
code 
print i 
print maxLength
```

So, what I have so far is a program that of course gets a value, what I need to do with this value, is create a loop that will compare the value of each integers value within range of integers between 1 and the user input or "n", than output the integer with the highest value, and what that value is within the range.

Comment: Your code has wrong indentation and logic. Please provide the input and the expected output

Comment: If I was to input 27 it would bring back the answer 30. I want it to run for the numbers 1-27 and to find the value of each one and compare them as it runs and to return the answer with the largest value and what number is associated with that value in the  range.

Comment: @Alex If you were to input a number and find the largest value from 1 to that number, wouldn't the largest value be the input itself. It seems I am missing something...

Comment: `for i in range(1, n - 1): i = i + 1` I am not sure if this does what you intented.

Comment: In the range I am running it uses the numbers in the range to run a calculation and that calculation will be different with every number.

Comment: I am wondering where I should start a for loop so that I can run the range that is going to run. Should it be before the while loop which does the calculation are should it be after the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 7
maxLength = 0 

for i in range(1, n+1):
    if i > maxLength:
        maxLength = i

print i 
print maxLength
```

---

I don't know why you would do this to..
And i don't know why you would iterate through a range as `i` and then add `i = i + 1` in the iteration, the `for` loop does that for you..

And you never made use of `length` at all in your logic so i removed it..

Again, i don't see any logic at all in your code..
Why not just:

```
n = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
for i in range(1, n+1):
    pass
print i
print n
```